# JSF2.0 + Eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, jsf, jsf-2, eclipse-wtp

I am following [this](http://help.eclipse.org/helios/index.jsp?topic=/org.eclipse.jst.jsf.doc.user/html/gettingstarted/tutorial/JSFTools_tutorial_JSF20.html) to build a JSF project in Eclipse. I am using Eclipse Galileo.

The problem I am facing is that it is mentioned to use DynamicWebModule version 2.5 to use JSF, but it is showing me upto version 2.4 only. How can I upgrade my DynamicWebModule version?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you selected a Servlet 2.4 *Target Runtime*?

The documentation you link to is for Helios. You would be better off using the [Galileo documentation](http://help.eclipse.org/galileo/topic/org.eclipse.jst.jsf.doc.user/html/gettingstarted/tutorial/JSFTools_tutorial.html). If you are going to target JSF 2.0, you would probably be better off upgrading from Galileo to Helios.

Comment: @McDowell- I have selected Apache Tomcat 5.5 in _target runtime_.

Comment: @user549757 [Apache Tomcat version 5.5 implements the Servlet 2.4 and JavaServer Pages 2.0 specifications](http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-5.5-doc/index.html) - upgrade to a newer version of Tomcat; 5.5 will not support Servlet 2.5